# Listview setEnabled() causing a null pointer exception

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a list view inside a dialog fragment. The list view works fine and is being set in `onActivityCreated()`. E.g.

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), list,
        R.layout.dialog_list_row, from, to);

mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

However, I'm not understanding why once I've added the `adapter` (as above) to my `listview`, why can't I access the children. E.g.

```
mListView.getChildAt(0).setEnabled(false);
```

I am performing this change to the list item in `onResume()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to quickly extend your adapter to return the proper value in isEnabled and areAllItemsEnabled.

Enabling the view won't work properly because of the view recycling in android.

## edit

a little code :

```
public class DisableAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

    public DisableAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        return position != 0;
    }
}
```

This simply disables the first item of the list. AFAIK, this is the proper way.

Answer (score 2):

ListView Items takes time to get display.Your code is getting executed as soon as it hits onResume method.

When setEnabled(false); is called on particular item your android has no idea if your listView has any child or not,since yet they are not rendered.

Try below snippet.

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
    int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        listView.setSelection(0); //So your listview will bring first child in focus.
        listView.getChildAt(0).setEnabled(false);

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I've implemented what you suggest but it still causes a null pointer (for your records). Which I find odd but this suggests that onScroll is called initially before the view has rendered fully (perhaps). Nice suggestion though.

Comment: I could work, but is more of a dirty hack. the enabling has nothing to do with scrolling, you are just abusing this method to know when the views are recycled. I probably doesn't work when you have several items, as the getChildAt(0) can be the first item visible, not the first of the list.

Answer (score 1):

because the children views are only there after the ListView started drawing, which happens after the resume.

Maybe you could extend the SimpleAdapter to make changes on the views before returning them.
for example:

```
public static class MyAdapter extends SimpleAdapter{

public MyAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, data, resource, from, to);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v =super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    v.setEnabled(false);
    return v;
}

}
```

Comment: I was hoping not to have to extend anything. But I'm beginning to think I can't do setEnable() how I would like. So I'll give this a go.